# App doesn't conform to protocol 'App' after adding arguments for parameters

Tags: xcode, swiftui

When I try to run my code I had an error in my app file for missing arguments for parameters in ContentView. Therefore I fixed this issue by entering arguments for the parameters.

Here is what I did (which resolved my previous error):

```
@main
struct Market_ExampleApp: App {

    @StateObject var appModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    @StateObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel = SharedDataModel()
    @Binding var shirtData : Shirt
    @Binding var showDetailShirt: Bool
    @Binding var trouserData : Trouser
    @Binding var showDetailTrouser: Bool

    init(shirtData: Binding<Shirt>, showDetailShirt: Binding<Bool>, trouserData: Binding<Trouser>, showDetailTrouser: Binding<Bool>){
        self._shirtData = shirtData
        self._showDetailShirt = showDetailShirt
        self._trouserData = trouserData
        self._showDetailTrouser = showDetailTrouser

        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    // Calling Delegate...
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(Appdelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(shirtData: $shirtData, showDetailShirt: $showDetailShirt, trouserData: $trouserData, showDetailTrouser: $showDetailTrouser)
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                    
                    Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

When I made these changes, it resolved the previous error. However now I get the error:

Type 'Market_ExampleApp' does not conform to protocol 'App'

Originally I thought an init was required for the app protocol and tried this method but it didn't work.

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  
    @AppStorage("log_status") var log_Status: Bool = false
    @StateObject var appModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    
    @StateObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel = SharedDataModel()
    
    @Binding var shirtData : Shirt
    @Binding var showDetailShirt: Bool

    @Binding var trouserData : Trouser
    @Binding var showDetailTrouser: Bool
    
    init(shirtData: Binding<Shirt>, showDetailShirt: Binding<Bool>, trouserData: Binding<Trouser>, showDetailTrouser: Binding<Bool>){
        self._shirtData = shirtData
        self._showDetailShirt = showDetailShirt
        self._trouserData = trouserData
        self._showDetailTrouser = showDetailTrouser
        
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            if log_Status{
                MainPage(shirtData: $shirtData, showDetailShirt: $showDetailShirt, trouserData: $trouserData, showDetailTrouser: $showDetailTrouser)
            }
            else{
                OnBoardingPage()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage code:

```
    @Binding var shirtData : Shirt
    @Binding var showDetailShirt: Bool

    @Binding var trouserData : Trouser
    @Binding var showDetailTrouser: Bool

    @Namespace var animation
    
    // Hiding Tab Bar...
    init(shirtData: Binding<Shirt>, showDetailShirt: Binding<Bool>, trouserData: Binding<Trouser>, showDetailTrouser: Binding<Bool>){
        self._shirtData = shirtData
        self._showDetailShirt = showDetailShirt
        self._trouserData = trouserData
        self._showDetailTrouser = showDetailTrouser
        
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
```

Struct for Shirt:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase

struct Shirt: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var shirt_name: String = ""
    var shirt_type: String = ""
    var shirt_image: String = ""
    var shirt_uid : String = ""
    var shirt_stock: Int = 0
}
```

Struct for Trouser:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase

struct Trouser: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var trouser_name: String = ""
    var trouser_type: String = ""
    var trouser_image: String = ""
    var trouser_uid : String = ""
}
```

MarketplaceShirtView (when a shirt is tapped it should take user to a detailed view). The code for MarketplaceTrouserView is identical

```
import SwiftUI

struct MarketplaceShirtView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppViewModel
    @StateObject var MarketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    @State private var selectedMarketplaceFilter: MarketplaceFilterViewModel = .shirt
    @Namespace var animation : Namespace.ID 
    @State var showDetailShirt = false
    @State var selectedShirt : Shirt!
    
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        var columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 2)
        
        ZStack{
            
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                                
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("Find Shirts To Buy")
                        
                    }
                
                 }
            }
                
                if MarketplaceModel.shirts.isEmpty{
                    
                    ProgressView()
                   
                }
                else{
                    
                    ScrollView {
                        

                        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(){
                            
                            ForEach(MarketplaceModel.filteredShirt){shirt in
                                                                
                                    ShirtView(shirtData: shirt)

                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            
                                                selectedShirt = shirt
                                                showDetailShirt.toggle()
     
                                        }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            
            if selectedShirt != nil && showDetailShirt{
                
                ShirtDetailView(shirtData: Binding($selectedShirt)!, showDetailShirt: $showDetailShirt,animation: _animation)
            }
}
}
```

Errors occur when ShirtDetailView is called. The errors are :

Cannot convert value '$showDetailShirt' of type 'Binding' to expected type 'Bool', use wrapped value instead

Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Shirt'

Comment: App is created by system... How were you going to create App with that init? Just curious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`App()` is the main component which starts running everything.

You can't have `@Binding` Variable in `App`, it will cause an error

> App does not conform to protocol App

Comment: Oh okay. When I take these out, I cannot enter the arguments for ContentView. I obviously get the error 'cannot find in scope' for the arguments. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I need to see what is inside your content view because that view is your main problem

Comment: I edited the question to show what's inside my content view

Comment: All your @ Binding variables inside ContentView are useless. It does nothing for ContentView at all. You can remove all these state/binding variables inside your App() and ContentView. You should initialize all those variables inside MainPage instead, then everything will run smoothly. Also do not use @ Binding inside the MainPage too. Use either @ State or @ ObservedObject.

Comment: I had issues initialising those variables in MainPage and it was recommended to use Binding. I will try to switch to what you said however I wasn't able to initialise these variables. I edited the question to show how MainPage is set up. It's the initialising bit I get errors when using State.

Comment: @ Binding is a special wrapper which is used ONLY for a SUB VIEW that needs to pass a data back to its parent view. In your case, the MainPage never pass anything back to ContentView, but you use @ Binding which is useless. To initialize your data in MainPage, use these instead: @ State var shirtData = Shirt(), @ State var showDetailShirt = false, @ State var tourserData = Trouser(), @ State var showDetailTrouser = false. Note you can give either true or false value to showDetailShirt/showDetailTrouser bases on desired design.

Comment: FINALLY, delete all those @ Binding and @ State variables in your APP() and CONTENTVIEW(). Also, when you call MainPage or ContentView, call without parameters. MainPage() / ContentView()

Comment: I see, that makes much more sense! The only issue I have after initialising like this is the error: Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call when I initialise @ State var shirtData = Shirt() & @ State var trouserData = Trouser()

Comment: Just fill out the required info of your Shirt() and Trouser(). I am sure you have variables inside that struct/class. It could be something like Shirt(var1:...., var2: ....)

Comment: I thought this was the case, when I tried this I got errors like: Cannot convert value of type 'String.Type' to expected argument type 'String'. Have I done this wrong? Part of Shirt is shirt_name so I entered: shirt_name : String. This is where I got the error

Comment: Include your shirt and trouser model in your code so I can check.

Comment: I've edited the question to show these

Comment: This one is an easy fix. Declare all your variables inside the model like this: var trousertype: String = “”. For var id you don’t have to, up to you. Now whenever you call Shirt() or Trouser() you dont have to pass anything to the parameters at the start.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks! Seems to have done the job for when i call Trouser() however i'm still having issues with the Shirt(). I still get the error Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call. It recommends inserting from: . Maybe this is because of an Int in the Trouser struct? I forgot to include this in my edit. I have updated the edit to show it. Maybe i declared in wrong in the Model?

Comment: Those are basic problems. Basically, whatever variables you have in your struct, you need to give it a ‘start up or initialized value’, so if it’s an Int just give it 0 because Int can’t store “”, if it’s a Double give it 0.0.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I think I have nearly done it. The errors I have now are in other places but are probably caused by the improvements made. In my MarketplaceShirtView & my MarketplaceTrouserView, I am getting an error when calling the detail view. I will edit the question to show the code